# How do I ssh into a server and run a bash script that requires bash variables and sshes into another server?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've tried the most popular solution to this, namely using the [-t parameter on ssh](https://www.google.com/search?q=run%20a%20command%20after%20shell) and running a command before bash initializes. Sadly, the script I am trying to run requires bash variables so this is not an option for me. These are the approaches I've tried:

**Approach 1:**

Just to show what I was trying above:

```
ssh -A me@proxy -t 'echo 0 | /usr/local/bin/hop-server.sh <parameters> && bash -l'
```

It sshes into the proxy but then it spits out a number of missing environment variables from the script.

**Approach 2:**

Added the script into ~/.bashrc:

```
if [ "$HOP" = "dev1" ]; then
    /usr/local/bin/hop-server.sh <parameters>
fi
```

And to connect:

```
ssh -A me@proxy -t 'HOP=dev1 bash -l'
```

This does not spit out environment variables as missing, but the hop does not succeed and I am stuck in the proxy:

```
me@proxy:~$  ~/proxytodev1
Setting environment variables...
Setting project...
Resolving 'dev1'...
Connecting to 123.123.123.123...
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-63-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

17 packages can be updated.
9 updates are security updates.

me@proxy:~$
```

Comment: What about specifying the variable when executing the script, similar to 1: `ssh -A me@proxy -t HOP=<dest> /usr/local/bin/hop-server.sh <params> && bash -l` though I'm not positive about the `bash -l` part which is why I'm keeping this as a comment instead of an answer

Comment: If you mean all of the environment variables that hop-server depends on, then no it is not possible. A couple dozen variables are being defined that allow this script to run.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ssh config option `SendEnv`

```
ssh -o 'SendEnv HOP' ...
```

Note that ssh server must be configured to accept it (`AcceptEnv` in sshd).

---

Alternatively, you can use the `.ssh/environment` file on the server side to set variables you want to be present on the ssh connection:

```
HOP=<destination>
```

For the server to accept it, you must set to true the `PermitUserEnvironment` sshd config option.

Comment: Is there any way to know if `AcceptEnv` is enabled as a non-privileged user? It doesn't seem to be working so I assume it's disabled. The problem with having a config on the server is that I need to be able to connect to multiple servers dev1, dev2, dev3, etc. so it needs to be defined from my computer.

Comment: By default, if no `AcceptEnv` is set on the server, no variable is accepted. However, default sshd config file set `LANG` and `LC_*` to be accepted. You can see it in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server.

Comment: Ah, I was looking for `/etc/sysconfig/sshd`. The line is `AcceptEnv LANG LC_*`, so maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: If it is there, it means that the server only accepts the `LANG` variable and ones that start with `LC_`. Since yours is `HOP`, it will not be accepted. You will need to edit this file to add `HOP` and reset the `sshd` daemon.

Comment: Ohhhhh. I get what you mean now. I'll see if I can get my system administrator to sign off on server hopping like this.

Comment: You could instead pass the variable from client as a parameter to the command, like this: `ssh ... ".../hop-server.sh $HOP ..."`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass environment variables to a process with this syntax:

```
foo=bar ./script.sh
```

will set `foo` to the value `bar` and pass it to the script. You can have as many of those `name=value` pairs as you want.

Just be careful with variable expansion; depending on which quotes you use, variables are expanded locally and then sent to the remote side or they are sent as is and then expanded remotely.

Comment: I can't pass environment variables into the script individually. There are many bash-specific variables and functions that are not being loaded in my first approach numbering in the dozens.

Comment: Can you give an example which variable you're missing and where it is defined?